# Getting extra quotes in fileuploader POST response

Tags: php, javascript

I am using Valum's fileuploader http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

The below index.html uploads a file, and post.php returns some json.  Sorry for not making a jsfiddle, but don't know how to implement the ajax response.

With FF, responseJSON.icon is

```
<img src="http://www.tapmeister.com/test/doc.png" width="32" height="32" />
```

With IE8, however, responseJSON.icon is

```
<IMG src='"http://www.tapmeister.com/test/doc.png"' width='"32"' height='"32"' >
```

I am okay with img being capitalized, however, those extra quotes are causing me havoc.

How is this fixed? Thank you

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link href="fileuploader.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
    <style>body {font-size:13px; font-family:arial, sans-serif; width:700px; margin:100px auto;}</style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
    <script src="fileuploader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>        
    $(function(){
        var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('file-uploader-demo1'),
            action: 'post.php',
            onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
                $('#icons').append('<li>'+responseJSON.icon+' '+$('<span/>').text(responseJSON.icon).html()+'</li>');
            },
            debug: true
        });
    });
     </script>
</head>

<body>      
    <div id="file-uploader-demo1"></div>
    <ul id="icons"></ul>    
</body>
</html>
```

post.php

```
<?php
$icon='<img src="http://www.tapmeister.com/test/doc.png" width="32" height="32" />';
$data=array('icon'=>$icon, 'other'=>'other data');
echo(json_encode($data));
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just send the URL of the image in your post.php and then build the IMG-Element in your javascript?

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array('icon' => 'http://google.de'));
?>
```

Create Image Using:

```
$('<img>').attr('src', responseJSON.icon); //...
```

Comment: Thanks theW0rld.  Probably will end up doing that if this is the only solution.

Comment: This answers the question.  If anyone knows other solutions, please post.  Thanks